# Normalize values within a range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a formula that will normalize values within a range so their average will equal the middle of the range?

For example, if I have the values

```
1,2,3,4,4,5
```

(note they are in the range of 1-5) then I would like each value adjusted so their average equals 3 (the middle of the range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the average and add 3:

```
select 3 + (t.x - avg(t.x) over ())
from t;
```

If you specifically want the middle of the range:

```
select (max(t.x) over () + min(t.x) over ()) / 2 + (t.x - avg(t.x) over ())
from t;
```

Comment: You should change the `(max - min) / 2` to `(max + min) / 2`. *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ba98ced60fc6baee171ed5759d04961a)*

Comment: Thank you, using that equation, the first value is adjusted to .84 which falls below the bottom of the range. Is there a way to ensure the adjusted values are still within the range?

Comment: @NickBoutelier: No, that's math. If you move things so that your average is a given one, then they move as much as they need to. There are more ways to normalize. The "normal" normalization is called *standard score*, subtract the *average* (this is called "centering") and divide by your *standard deviation* (this is called "reducing"). For non-gaussian distributions, it is quite common to subtract the *min* and divide by the *range*. Look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)#Examples) for more examples.